Interactive Email Page || Update <title> tag
While working in Interactive Emails, I noticed that the system adds some default code above your Interactive Email Form page![check highlighted in yellow screenshot]

Hence my title is over written by the default  and I dont see my title on browser tab :(

Does anyone know how to update the  without any workarounds?
or Am I doing anything wrong here!


I was able to update the title with this simple JS hack. This worked :)
    <script>document.title = "Update Your Preferences";</script>

Any Suggestions/feedback are welcome
